# How to combine button 'Back' with persistent storage?

Tags: flutter

My button 'Back' invokes `Navigator.pop(context)`. However, the previous page shows already outdated information.

Is there a way to force data reloading for the route after navigating to it?

Comment: i think you can pass back the value while poping and update the stacked or previous screen with the new value you pass while .pop

Comment: Yes, it would make sense if I wanted to refresh just some pages. However, the stored data may change because of number of reasons (like updated by other service or from other device), so I want every page to refresh after navigation, without having to care about it.

Comment: so did you tried initiating a function with initState() with maybe some Future.delayed which will refresh every screen on rebuild or navigation, I think that might serve the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: I found better option and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

I found, to refresh the state after navigation, I need to use `onGenerateRoute` instead of `routes` and set `maintainState` to false:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
      onGenerateRoute: _generateRoute,
    );
  }

  Route<dynamic> _generateRoute(s) {
    var page = routeToPage(s.name);
    return MaterialPageRoute<void>(
      builder: (context) => page.builder(context),
      settings: RouteSettings(name: page.route),
      maintainState: false,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to utilize the package [provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple), a mechanism to ensure flutter rebuilds everything modified.